# Why am I getting an error? Pygame blits

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, blit

```
import sys, pygame, math, random
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 1000,720
x = 0
y = 0


house1x = 500
house1y = 360

house2x = 1470
house2y = 360


rock1x = -100
rock1y = 300


scrollx = 0
scrolly = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
counter = 0


playercollideRect =  pygame.rect.Rect((0, 0), (75, 25))

house1collideRect = pygame.rect.Rect((0, 0), (870, 605))
house2collideRect = pygame.rect.Rect((0, 0), (870, 605))

rock1collideRect = pygame.rect.Rect((0, 0), (140, 100))



collision = False


lastkey = 'down'
animationdirection = 'down'



playerimage = pygame.image.load("img/player/player0.png").convert_alpha()
playerimagerect = playerimage.get_rect()


house1image = pygame.image.load("img/structures/house1.png").convert_alpha()
house1imagerect = house1image.get_rect()

house2image = pygame.image.load("img/structures/house2.png").convert_alpha()
house2imagerect = house2image.get_rect()


rock1image = pygame.image.load("img/objects/rock1.png").convert_alpha()
rock1imagerect = rock1image.get_rect()



clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screencolor = 0, 155, 20
gamefont = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 30)

playeranimationdown = ['img/player/player1.png','img/player/player0.png','img/player/player2.png','img/player/player0.png']
playeranimationup = ['img/player/playerback1.png','img/player/playerback0.png','img/player/playerback2.png','img/player/playerback0.png']
playeranimationleft = ['img/player/playerleft1.png','img/player/playerleft0.png','img/player/playerleft2.png','img/player/playerleft0.png']
playeranimationright = ['img/player/playerright1.png','img/player/playerright0.png','img/player/playerright2.png','img/player/playerright0.png']


pygame.mixer.music.load('audio/music/ambient.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(pygame.constants.USEREVENT)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')
pygame.event.set_allowed([pygame.QUIT, pygame.KEYDOWN, pygame.KEYUP])

colliders = [house1collideRect, house2collideRect, rock1collideRect]
blitrects = [house1imagerect, house2imagerect, rock1imagerect]
blitimages = [house1image, house2image, rock1image]
blitypositions = [rock1y, house1y, house2y]

while 1:

    clock.tick(500)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    if y > 720-75-100:
        y = 720-75-100
        scrolly -= 1
    if y < 0+75+100:
        y = 0+75+100
        scrolly += 1
    if x > 1000-37-100:
        x=1000-37-100
        scrollx -=1
    if x < 0+37+100:
        x = 0+37+100
        scrollx +=1


    for collider in colliders:
        if playercollideRect.colliderect(collider):
            if lastkey == 'left':
                x += 1
            if lastkey == 'right':
                x -= 1
            if lastkey == 'up':
                y += 1
            if lastkey == 'down':
                y -= 1
            collision = True
        else:
            collision = False


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            y -= 1

            if not collision == True:
                playerimage = pygame.image.load(playeranimationup[int(math.floor(counter/50))]).convert_alpha()
                counter = (counter + 1) % 200
            lastkey = 'up'


        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y += 1
            if not collision == True:
                playerimage = pygame.image.load(playeranimationdown[int(math.floor(counter/50))]).convert_alpha()
                counter = (counter + 1) % 200
            lastkey = 'down'


        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x += 1
            if not collision == True:
                playerimage = pygame.image.load(playeranimationright[int(math.floor(counter/50))]).convert_alpha()

                counter = (counter + 1) % 200
            lastkey = 'right'

        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x -= 1

            if not collision == True:
                playerimage = pygame.image.load(playeranimationleft[int(math.floor(counter/50))]).convert_alpha()

                counter = (counter + 1) % 200
            lastkey = 'left'




    playerimagerect.centerx = x
    playerimagerect.centery = y


    house1imagerect.centerx = house1x+scrollx
    house1imagerect.centery = house1y+scrolly

    house2imagerect.centerx = house2x+scrollx
    house2imagerect.centery = house2y+scrolly



    playercollideRect.midbottom = playerimagerect.midbottom

    house1collideRect.midbottom = house1imagerect.midbottom
    house2collideRect.midbottom = house2imagerect.midbottom

    rock1collideRect.midbottom = rock1imagerect.midbottom


    realx = x-scrollx
    realy = y-scrolly



    for image, imagerect, imageypos in blitimages, blitrects, blitypositions:
        if realy < imageypos:
            screen.blit(playerimage, playerimagerect)
            screen.blit(image, imagerect)
        if realy > imageypos:
            screen.blit(image, imagerect)
            screen.blit(playerimage, playerimagerect)

        if realy == imageypos:
            screen.blit(image, imagerect)
            screen.blit(playerimage, playerimagerect)





    label = gamefont.render(str('FPS: '+str(clock.get_fps())), 1, (255,255,0))
    screen.blit(label, (50, 50))

    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.fill(screencolor)
```

That's the code for a small project I'm working on but for some reason I'm getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\python kick\game\game.py", line 186, in <module>
screen.blit(image, imagerect)
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit
```

Any insight on my problem? I've been testing and searching for quite a while.

Comment: You are simply using `Screen().blit()` wrong. The second argument should be a two tuple pair. The first element being a positive integer for the _**x**_ position of the image, and the second should be the _**y**_ position of the image. I suggest [reading more about how to properly use the function at the official Documentation for Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit).

Comment: @ChistianDean thanks! I used zip() to fix this problem

Comment: If you have an error in a function or code snippet then please build a short [mcve] around that function/code snippet that demonstrates the error or problem. There is almost never a reason to post 100+ lines of code.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman ok ill keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `screen.blit(image, (x coordinate, y coordinate))` you're passing the rect not the coordinates. If you wanted to use the coordinates in the rect they're `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y`.